# How to resolve Invalid header signature; read 0x6576206C6D783F3C, expected 0xE11AB1A1E011CFD0 error java?

Tags: java, excel, io, filestream

I am exporting a file from a web application which is in .xls format. When I am trying to read this file, it is throwing error as:

> java.io.IOException: Invalid header signature; read 0x6576206C6D783F3C, expected 0xE11AB1A1E011CFD0

This is an exported file so could not change the format.

Here is my code and attached is the excel file:

```
public void verifyExportedData() throws Exception{
    String filename = "Top_Down_Planning_by_Investment.xls"      
    File=new FileInputStream(new File("testdata/"+filename));
    HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(File);
    HSSFSheet sheet=workbook.getSheet("Top Down Planning by Investmen");
    DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
    System.out.println("Cell data : "+sheet.getRow(0).getCell(1));
}
```

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "expected" and "actual" file signatures are being output in the reverse order to normal.  (It is probably a big-endian versus little-endian thing ...)

According to a source I found on the web, the file signature for a ".xls" file is

```
  D0 CF 11 E0 A1 B1 1A E1
```

which matches the "expected" signature (reversed).  So if I reverse the "actual" signature, I get

```
  3C 3F 78 6D 6C 20 76 65
```

If I convert those hex code to ASCII I get

```
  '<' '?' 'x' 'm' 'l' ' ' 'v' 'e'
```

or

```
  <?xml ve
```

Is this looking familiar?  Here's a typical XML file header:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
```

You appear to have exported the file as an XML-based format rather than the legacy ".xls" format.  I am guessing the file is in ".xlxs" format or similar.

I think that you need to use XSSF rather than HSSH:

- https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @Stephen C ! I am exporting the file in .xls format which is getting transformed from an XML based format from application. There is a link in application as "Export to Excel" which is giving this excel file. Any idea how can I read it successfully or make it a .xls header format??